# Cesaro summability of nonnegative bounded sequence

Tags: analysis

let $a_{n}$ be a nonnegative and bounded sequence. Prove or disprove the Cesaro sum of $a_{n}$ convergence

I have no idea.

Answer (score 6):

Make all terms either $1$ or $0$, starting with a $1$. Let $s_n$ be the sum of the first $n$ terms. Whenever you find $s_n/n \ge 2/3$, insert a sequence of $0$'s until you reach an $m$ such that $s_m/m \le 1/3$. At that point start inserting $1$'s until you reach a $k$ so that $s_k/k \ge 2/3.$ Continuing in this way you wind up with a sequence for which the terms $s_j/j$ do not converge, since they are infinitely often at most $1/3$ and at least $2/3$. So this sequence has no Cesaro sum.

There may be a way to get a formula for exactly when to switch between $1$ and $0$ and vice versa in this sequence, but there's no real need for that.